# neo4j cypher will not update database

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

following code gets error "result undefined" (last error trap) please help:

```
try {
    var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7474", neo4j.auth.basic(userName, passWord));
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
const session = driver.session();
const personName = 'Alice';

try {
    const resultPromise = session.run('CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a', {
        name: personName
    });
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
try {
    resultPromise.then(
        result => {
            session.close();
            const singleRecord = result.records[0];
            const node = singleRecord.get(0);
            console.log(node.properties.name);
            driver.close();
        }
    );
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
```

Comment: fixedm thanks, ligisima

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to the fact that you are using the java bolt driver on the http port (7474) of Neo4j.

Just change the connection url by this one : `neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic(userName, passWord))`